# How to instantiate user defined class with ToolBox.eval at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I wrote the following code.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

class A

object Main extends App {
  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  tb.eval(tb.parse("new A"))
}
```

This simple code try to instantiate class A, but scala throw an exception.

```
[error] (run-main-0) scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:
[error] 
[error] not found: type A
[error] scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:
[error] 
[error] not found: type A
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:331)
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.wrapInPackageAndCompile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:213)
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:267)
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.$anonfun$compile$13(ToolBoxFactory.scala:444)
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:370)
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:437)
[error]     at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.eval(ToolBoxFactory.scala:459)
[error]     at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:9)
[error]     at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:5)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
[error]     at Main$.main(Main.scala:5)
[error]     at Main.main(Main.scala)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

However, not user defined class like Map can instantiate; `tb.eval(tb.parse("Map[String, Int]()"))` works well.

How can I instantiate user defined class with ToolBox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486653/scala-how-to-instantiate-an-interpreter-that-inherits-the-current-context/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare class A "in that scope":

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Main extends App {
  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  tb.eval(tb.parse("class A; new A"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your answer means that the class which has been already compiled cannot instantiate with ToolBox?

Comment: You basically need to compile the class with Toolbox, if you don´t it is like you are in a different scope. Btw upvote is appreciated ;)

Comment: I used `import` to put class A into scope and it looks works fine. thank. Btw, Map can be used without special process because ToolBox's implementer put it into the ToolBox's scope?

Comment: Something like that yeah